# is there any easier or shorter way to write this code?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a shorter way to write this code?

```
uasort($my_array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['number'] == $b['number'])
        return 0;
    elseif ($a['number'] < $b['number'])
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
});
```

This works, but I need to repeat this code many times.

Is there a better way to do it?

Specifically is there a better way to do it in Laravel?

Comment: Wrap it in a function you can call, or use iteration to make it more DRY

Comment: If you're using PHP7, you have the "spaceship" operator (`<=>`) and can do `return $a['number'] <=> $b['number'];` alternatively why not just do `return $a['number'] - $b['number'];`

Comment: `return $a['number'] == $b['number'] ? 0 : $a['number'] < $b['number'] ? 1 : -1`

Comment: well.. i dont have php  :/ -- and can i just put this in another function? i mean.. it is allready a function

Comment: Yes, you can wrap it in a function that you can call 10 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Laravel collection if you want:

```php
$my_array = collect($my_array)->sortBy('number')->all();
```

Comment: this really works fine :o but in the other way around.. i dont want it like 1,2,3,4 - it should be 4,3,2,1 - so you know how i can do this?

Comment: As you can read here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortbydesc you would simply use `$my_array = collect($my_array)->sortByDesc('number')->all();`